# Show that $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)g(x) = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f, g: \mathbb R\setminus{x_0} \to \mathbb R$ functions such that

$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = L \in \mathbb R$ where $L > 0$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x) = \infty$

Show that $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)g(x) = \infty$

Can I divide these like $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) * \lim_{x\to x_0} g(x) = L * \infty = \infty$, doesnt seem really intuitive though.

Comment: This is a standard theorem about the "algebra of limits". A proof follows: let $M >0$ be arbitrary. Since $f(x) > 2M/L$ in a neighbourhood of $x_0$, and $g(x) > L/2$ in another neighbourhood of $x_0$, in the intersection of these two neighbourhoods you have $$f(x)g(x)>\frac{2M}{L} \frac{L}{2}=M$$ and you are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite that simple because you are being asked to *prove* that "distributing the limit" is a valid step here.

You should approach this using the definition of limit. $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)g(x)=\infty$ provided that given $N>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that whenever $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$, $f(x)g(x)>N$.

How can you ensure $f(x)g(x)>N$? Well given any $\epsilon>0$ we can choose $\delta_1$ so that if $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $f(x) \in (L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$. We certainly want $f(x)>0$, so let's choose $\epsilon=\frac{L}{2}$.Then this says if we are "close enough" to $x_0$, $\frac{L}{2}<f(x)<\frac{3L}{2}$.

Now in order to have $f(x)g(x)>N$, we just need $g(x)>\frac{N}{L/2}$. But because $\lim_{x \to x_0}g(x)=\infty$, there exists $\delta_2>0$ so that if $0<|x-x-0|<\delta_2$, then $g(x)> \frac{N}{L/2}$.

Finally, just take $\delta$ to be the smaller of $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ so that we have both $f(x)>\frac{L}{2}$ and $g(x)>\frac{N}{L/2}$ whenever $0 <|x-x_0|<\delta$.